# PHP Laravel Says I Am Inserting Null But Function Should Return String

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am generating customer IDs for each customer after they make an order in a Laravel 5 application. What follows is the code to generate an ID for the customer, which is composed of part of their first name, last name, and if this renders a duplicate, a random string is appended.

```
$ID = strtolower(substr($itemsP['firstName'],0,2) . $itemsP['lastName']);

function checkforduplicateID($iD,$firstName,$lastName)
{
    $f = $firstName;
    $l = $lastName;
    $orders = Order::where('customerID',$iD)->get()->count();

    if($orders>0)
    {
        $ID = strtolower(substr($firstName,0,2) . $lastName . substr(md5(rand()),0,2)); 
        checkforduplicatecode($ID,$f,$l);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return $iD; 
    }
}

$sessionOrder->customerID = checkforduplicateID($ID,$itemsP['firstName'],$itemsP['lastName']);
$sessionOrder->save();
```

On the first go around (no duplicate) this works perfectly. But as soon as I have two customers with the same first and last name, the function returns a `null` rather than the same ID with an appended (and random) string.

So I am getting an integrity violation on the second to last line because I am inserting a `null` into my database.

Something is obviously wrong with my `checkforduplicateID` function, but I can't figure out what.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that here

```
if($orders>0) {
    $ID = strtolower(substr($firstName,0,2) . $lastName . substr(md5(rand()),0,2));
    checkforduplicatecode($ID,$f,$l);
} else {
```

you need to return the new ID like this:

```
if($orders>0) {
    $ID = strtolower(substr($firstName,0,2) . $lastName . substr(md5(rand()),0,2));
    return checkforduplicateID($ID,$f,$l);
} else {
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct, if there is more than zero matching orders nothing should be returned because the function needs to run again until no orders match, -and then- return the ID.

Comment: you're not looping like that...what does checkforduplicatecode() do?  is that supposed to call the same function?  even so, you'll need to return what it produces.

Comment: assuming that checkforduplicateID() was the intended self looping structure, i updated the solution.

Comment: Ah thank you. Did not realize I needed to return like that to get it to loop like I wanted. *tips hat*

Comment: *tips hat in return*